# How to redirect after success from ajax call using React?

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, rest, reactjs

I'm new on using ReactJS and I want to know how to redirect after success from ajax call using React without react-route or flux ? 
Is that possible ? Can someone help me please

Answer (score 0):

You can change window.location.href in your ajax callback to redirect browser to a new url.

Answer (score 0):

I've not played much with React with React-routes. But You can use JS version.

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect 
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com"); 

// similar behavior as clicking on a link 
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Source from [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-page-redirect-using-jquery)